# Proper subgroup of a $p$-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $H$ a proper subgroup such that $|H|=p^s$. I want to prove that there exists $H'$ subgroup of $G$ such that $H\subset H'$ and $|H'|=p^{s+1}$.

I don't know if induction would be a nice way. For $s=0$, we just need to take an element of order $p$, by Cauchy's theorem. But in general case, I don't see how to obtain subgroups with its order smaller than $|H|$ to apply induction.

Is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216913/do-finite-p-groups-have-subgroups-of-all-possible-orders-containing-a-given-no) might be what you are looking for.